Medal of Honor: Allied Assault doesn't run
My cousin bought an edition of MOHAA, including two CDS. CDs already had an owner before that.
After installation, he tried to run the game and failed, and it doesn't even appear in the Task Manager. He even ran the game shortcut as Administrator in the program files folder, as well as running it in compatibility mode, and nothing changed.
What can he do to solve this problem? I searched for some patches on the internet, but none of them indicate that they can resolve this in their descriptions.
NOTE: I know this game is known for some glitches, even after the game runs, such as events not triggering, preventing the player from continuing. However, my cousin has a good computer and the person he bought the game from never had any problems playing it.

Did you try running the game executable in compatibility mode for... Windows 7 I guess is probably as far back as you can go?
